# How do I convert WAV to FLAC and FLAC to OGG?

Tags: convert, ogg-vorbis, flac, wav

How do I convert a Waveform Audio File (".wav") to the Free Lossless Audio Codec (".flac")? In addition, how do I convert Free Lossless Audio Codec (".flac") files to Ogg Vorbis (".ogg") files, for use on mobile devices?

The requirement to convert WAV files to the FLAC is only for a *single* file and I don't anticipate that I will need to do this again anytime soon (I honestly don't even *remember* the last time I used a WAV file!), but the requirement to convert FLAC files to OGG will be an *ongoing* requirement (usually for a folder-at-a-time), as I rip my CDs into the FLAC for playback on "powerful" devices with "decent" speakers/audio output (the Sony PlayStation 3, the computer, etc...) and use OGG *exclusively* on my mobile devices (my smartphone, my tablet, etc...).

I am *semi-competent* with Terminal and am not "scared" to use it as some people understandably are (in fact for many things, I *prefer* it)... But with regards to this *particular* task, I would prefer to use something with a *graphical* interface where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Gnormilize.

[Gnormalize](http://gnormalize.sourceforge.net/) is a GTK based tool for audio conversion. In addition to converting audio (between mp3, mp4, mpc, wav, ogg, ape and flac), Gnormalize can adjust the volume of sound files to compensate for varying recording levels. You can also use Gnormalize to rip CDs, edit metadata and play your songs as well.<sup>[Gnormaliz](http://gnormalize.sourceforge.net/)e</sup>

Comment: Ugh, it had to be tar.gz... I hate those things, so much work for so little benefit. Anyway, you have answered my question, so thanks buddy!

Answer (score 15):

For wav > flac :

```
ffmpeg -i FILE.wav FILE.flac
```

For wav > ogg

```
ffmpeg -i FILE.wav FILE.ogg
```

For wav > ogg - Batch mode

```
for i in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$i".ogg ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think the batch mode bit results in file names looking like `whateverthesongname.wav.ogg`; so with a double extension. Something like the following would work to get just a `.ogg` file name: `for i in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$(basename "$i" .wav)".ogg ; done`. Picked up from [here](https://lonewolfonline.net/convert-wav-mp3-linux/).

Answer (score 6):

Install [Soundconverter](http://soundconverter.org/) from [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/synaptic-package-manager-beginners-guide-for-ubuntu-users.html) or install it from within a shell prompt with

> sudo apt-get install soundconverter

Once installed, launch it, and click on the Preferences icon to set your default output format to OGG (which you can override when you need to convert to other formats).